# Moving instance object moves instances

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm attempting to make a procedural wall with geometry nodes (Blender v3). When I move the object instanced on the line, the whole wall moves.
[image: node diagram]

Currently my collection only has a single object. I'd think I should be able to move the wall segment without the whole wall also moving.

Why is the whole wall moving when I move my wall segment? Is there a way to prevent it?

File:
[image]

Comment: It does look like a bug, you can report that Inside Blender going to Help > Report Bug. Found something about the way the collection works [HERE](https://developer.blender.org/D12478) but it's not clear about the movement, BUT!! If you click Separate Children and Reset Children, that helps to move the original one.

Comment: @Emir considering the separate and reset children seems to do what I want maybe this is the intended way of things?

Comment: Probably, but i'm not really sure about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable *Separate Children* and *Reset Children*.

[image]

Instancing works differently with a collection than it does with an object.

A collection has an origin point, which is not tied to the origin points of the objects it contains. All the contained objects will be instanced relatively to the collection's origin point.

If you want to offset globally the collection instance origin point, you can go into the collection properties and tweak these values :

[image]

If you look into the [collection info node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/collection_info.html) docs you'll see that *Separate Children*  will output each children as a separate instance as opposed to instancing the whole collection as a unique instance containing multiple meshes grouped into it. You won't notice anything right away in the viewport when enabling it, but each object will be instanced separately.

Then you'll see that *Reset Children*  will reset the children's unapplied transforms. This means not only the translation, but also the scale and the rotation so do keep that in mind when resetting the children : It discards all unapplied transforms.

[image]

Comment: out of curiosity is there a easy method for creating little gifs? I'm assuming screen capture and then convert to gif with some tool, but maybe there is a single tool?

Comment: @depperm I personaly use ScreenToGif because that's the first one I've tested and it's really simple to use it but there are a lot of alternatives : https://alternativeto.net/software/screentogif/ most are free, some are even open source